# Erasing incorrect entries in Overleaf spell-checker

Tags: spelling, overleaf

I use Overleaf for my projects in Danish language. The spell checker is working, but it seems that I have coincidentally registered some words in incorrect spelling.

[image: this screen dump]

In this screen dump is shown how correction to a correct word is suggested providing several mis-spelled alternatives.
How do I delete these misspellings?

Comment: Currently there's no mechanism for doing so from the editor (sorry!), but you can send an email to support@overleaf.com, and they can remove the erroneous entry from your dictionary. (I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.)

Comment: @LianTzeLim Would you like to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: @samcarter I wasn't actually sure if this question would be removed; as it's not directly related to LaTeX, so I thought a comment would work better. If the question is fine as it is to remain, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*(Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.)*

*[Updated Sep, 2022]* The feature is now live. You can remove entries from your custom dictionary from the Project settings menu:

[image: Screenshot of dictionary edit button in Overleaf menu]

Comment: I was looking for this feature. Any plans to include this in the near future?

Comment: This is a mission-critical feature that should be added asap!

Comment: It has been more than 3 years since this question was asked. I agree that this feature should be added asap!

Comment: I agree. This should be a feature for the user.

Comment: I've filed a bug report here: https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf/issues/882

Answer (score 7):

As of writing several years later, this seems to still remain an issue.

I've filed a bug report here:
https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf/issues/882

Answer (score 4):

You can now remove words from your custom dictionary: from the editor menu (top-left button) in the settings section, click on the "Dictionary -- Edit" button.
Hope that helps!

*(This feature is currently in beta; you can join the beta program [here](https://www.overleaf.com/beta/participate))*

Comment: It seems it is available without enrolling in the beta now.