# How can I add a word in overleaf to the spell checker?

Tags: overleaf, thesis, spelling, spell

I am writing my thesis with overleaf. The spell checker does not recognize some words. How can I add them ?

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Your question is not about syntax checking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with LaTeX, but is about a specific feature of Overleaf. For this reason, the question should be addressed to the Overleaf team.

Comment: Hope this will be reopened. Many TeX users use Overleaf, the answer might be useful for them. I am an example of this, I googled for an answer and google brought me here!

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: Have you tried right-clicking on a unrecognized word and clicking Add to dictionary? how to:**

[image]

Your question is not about LaTeX nor syntax-highlighting as proposed by @jose.

I recommend you contacting overleaf support at https://www.overleaf.com/contact

As you are writing thesis, You do not have to bother about spell check, don't you? Because the `.tex` or `PDF` output does not contain spell checked information.

Also, I would like to recommend going to the [Github repository of overleaf](https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf) and posting a Issue. Note: [one](https://github.com/overleaf/overleaf/issues/882) have been created but have not gotten any response :(

At lastly, you can write to support@overleaf.com about the issue/improvement as [suggested](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360481/erasing-incorrect-entries-in-overleaf-spell-checker?rq=1#:%7E:text=Currently%20there%27s%20no%20mechanism%20for%20doing%20so%20from%20the%20editor%20(sorry!)%2C%20but%20you%20can%20send%20an%20email%20to%20support%40overleaf.com%2C%20and%20they%20can%20remove%20the%20erroneous%20entry%20from%20your%20dictionary.%20(I%27m%20a%20support%20personnel%20at%20Overleaf.)) by @imnothere.